# probability of winning X games out of Y games, given the probability of winning 1 game

Tags: probability

If the probability of winning 1 game is 'p' , then what is the probability of winning ' X games out of y games'?

my approach was to first , figure out in how many ways can we select, X games out of a total of y games, and then multiply that by the probability of winning those X games.
or, yCx * p^x . is this correct?

Comment: Are you familiar with the binomial distribution?

Comment: never heard of it,

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Answer (score 2):

This is an exact application of the [Binomial Distribution formula](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/probability/binomial.html) for *exactly* $x$ successful trials in '$N$ attempts where the probability of success in each trial is $p$ :

$$P(x) = {N \choose x} p^x (1-p)^{N-x}$$

It is very similar to your approach with the distinction that the rest of the games must be lost.

If you wish to have at least $x$ successful attempts, the value will be $$\sum_{k=x}^N P(k)$$

Comment: I got to the nCx * p^x part, but no idea how (1-p)^n-x got in there.

Comment: That is the probability that the rest of the games will be lost. I have added more content to the answer, could u please refresh and take a look.

Comment: done. got it. thanks a lot!